# What does this explanation about using 'seal' verb mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

[Explanation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seal):

> 3. Fry (food) briefly at a high temperature to prevent it from losing moisture during subsequent cooking

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjfDW-kcX5E)

---

According to the explanation, its description fits 'sear' meaning

**Question:**

> What does this explanation mean if it isn't sear or cauterization?

Comment: If you quickly fry/sear/brown something like *meat* before the main (slower) cooking phase, the outside surface of the meat will "shrink" from the heat, which helps to retain moisture/juices. But this is about general knowledge / cookery, not the use of English as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... or not: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59807/is-sealing-in-the-flavor-an-actual-thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about cooking, not about English.

Comment: @JavaLatte 1 We discussed the meaning of the word which happened to pertain to cooking, nevertheless, we didn't discuss how to cook better- we discussed meaning of the word (as I said) and difference between words 'sear' and 'seal' and as you can conclude, it is difficult to discern the difference without plunging into cooking process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In culinary, the term "seal" is mainly used in recipes of preparing meat. It means 
frying at a high temperature so that the meat you're cooking won't lose its juicy moisture while being prepared.

Example from the link you provided:

> Heat the oil and seal the lamb on both sides

*To sear* means to burn slightly and superficially so as to affect color. The effect (brown color) may be similar if you seal the meat, but to seal you use a frying pan, and to sear -- a grill.

Answer (score 2):

To **seal** something **in** means to take measures to prevent it from getting out.

You can put someone behind a brick wall, toss in your torch to consume the remaining oxygen, and then seal them in.  (Edgar Allan Poe allusion)

You can seal meat juices in by searing it at high temperature.

By extension, **to seal meat** means to seal in its juices (by searing).

Comment: (Technically, you can't, seal meat juices, but yes, otherwise I agree.)

Comment: @Stephie:   But we can seal meat juices *in*.

Comment: Just as we cannot lock a prisoner, but we can lock him *in*.

Comment: In the US, we can even seal *freshness* in. I saw it on the TV.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I assumed she was pointing out that the notion of searing meat to seal in juices is itself a falsehood.  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59807/is-sealing-in-the-flavor-an-actual-thing

Comment: I'm still gonna heed grandma's advice, *pace*  Harold McGee. The juices lost are caramelized onto the meat.

Comment: The "in" must have evaporated in the hot pan... but yes, as @Adam pointed out, I was talking about food chemistry, not grammar.